# How do I display the "real userid" on whose behalf a service is making the connection to the SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, service

We have a three tier application where the UI connects to a service and the service then uses a standard account to connect to the SQL Server using integrated authentication. On a busy system, it would be helpful to know the application user on whose behalf the service account is making a connection to the SQL Server. Is there a standard mechanism for doing so ? I am thinking of (mis)using the SqlConnection properties ApplicationName or WorkstationID for this purpose. The service layer would set these properties to the application user on the SqlConnection and the sp_who2 output would then display the user information. Thus if 'UserX' logged into the application and Service account 'ServiceUser' connected to the SQL Server, 'UserX' would show under ProgramName and 'ServiceUser' under Login. Would this have a negative impact on connection pooling ? Are there any disadvantages of using approach ?

Comment: SQL Server can only tell you what it knows about. Your service is going to have to pass that info along (as you suggest, you can spoof the connection string with various attributes). In the end, though, I think you'll find that it is much more secure to have your service authenticate as the caller instead of using a generic account for everyone. It's a little more work to get AD fully rolled into SQL Server, but if auditing is important, it's kind of the only way.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, how do I get the service to authenticate as the caller ? The service is running in a separate process while the "real" user is being authenticated by windows (or maybe a identity server).  Great if you can point  to some documentation on how to achieve this. Auditing is important but the service does provide the username to the DML operations.

Comment: I don't know anything about your service - what language / framework / library it's written in, how it is connecting to SQL Server, etc. This sounds like a different question: "How do I make my service (written in {language x}) pass the caller's AD credentials to SQL Server using {provider y}?" Assuming the language can retrieve the caller's AD username then the simplest path is probably to use session context as David suggested, or fall back to something else it can add to the connection string (like hijacking ApplicationName).

Answer (score 2):

> Would this have a negative impact on connection pooling ?

Yes.  The connection pool is partitioned by connection string, so you would have a connection pool per user.  But if you limit the connection pools size, the impact may not be material.

Alternatively you can call [sp_set_session_context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) after connecting to add data to the session identifying the end user.

Comment: The Key/Value pairs set using sp_set_session_context are not visible to sp_who2, right ?